# mysql_connect error 500

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I have narrowed down my problem to the `mysql_connect` call I am doing in PHP.
It produces an error message.  What would you suggest I should do to fix the problem with this error:

> Error Summary
>   HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
>
> > Detailed Error Information
> >     Module IsapiModule
> >     Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
> >     Handler PHP
> >     Error Code 0x00000000
> >     Requested URL http://localhost:80/getuser.php?q=3&sid=0.2953613724031635
> >     Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\getuser.php
> >     Logon Method Anonymous
> >     Logon User Anonymous
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
> - IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
> - IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
> - The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
> - The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> - Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
> - Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
> - Verify the permissions for the DLL.
> - Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
> - Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.
>
> Links and More InformationThis error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
>
> Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:
>
> - 294807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check phpinfo() for presence of MySQL functions. If those exist, try connecting to other MySQL servers. Try to narrow down if the problem is with your code, your PHP library, your SQL server or your web server by changing variables. CHeck for logs, I know Apache has an error log where detailed PHP error information goes -- IIS probably has something similar. Consider recompiling and reinstalling PHP.

Comment: I wrote a small php file with just one line:
<?php  phpinfo();  ?>
which produced a display.
MySQL functions are not in the display.
Should they be?

Comment: Yup. That's your problem. Reinstall PHP with MySQL extensions: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Though Avinash mentioned apache, he may be on the right track in the sense that you could be missing the actual library for mysql to interact with IIS.  I didn't read through the whole thing, but this may help you out: http://www.atksolutions.com/articles/install_php_mysql_iis.html

Also, I saw your response to Josh... You should have a table in your phpinfo for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder to new version PHP users:

**mysql_connect** was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Example (MySQLi Object-Oriented) of you should use instead of myslq_connect:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

check you apache conf file
and remove comment from the line below
(simply remove # from begining of the line)

LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so

Comment: I am running IIS, not apache.