# Mysql 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, mysql

I am using simple query for getting data from table using DbConnect() in php. If I use join, webpage is giving Internal Server Error and if I use simple query without join no error is there, it works perfectly.
Also when I try to open tables from phpmyadmin it gives same(500 Internal server error) error.
Is this error related to table size/ data/ format ?

What can we do for fix this error.

Comment: See your server logfiles for more informations

Answer (score 0):

Probably, php is missing MySQL functions.
I think its duplicated question
see [mysql_connect error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124268/mysql-connect-error-500)